# PDE Linear, Semilinear, quasilinear

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Classify the equation $\sqrt{(u_x)^2+(u_y)^2}=1$ if is linear, semilinear or quasilinear.

Hello Math Stack! :) . I don't understand how it classified, but the equation is not linear?

Comment: It's just a matter of definitions. What are the definitions of linear, semilinear and quasilinear equations?

Comment: Thanks. If the operators $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ are linear, I can say that the square $(u_x)^2$ and $(u_y)^2$ are linear? Therefore, the equation is linear?

Comment: No. First of all, you say operators, but show two derivatives of functions, which are therefore functions too. Second the square of something linear is not linear. I asked you what the definitions are, why don't you start there? Just write down the definitions in your question.

Comment: Definition: The PDE is linear if $F$ is affine with respect $(z,p,H,..., M).$ In other words, $F(x,az+(1-a)z',ap+(1-a)p', aH+(1-a)H',..., aM+(1-a)M')=aF(x,z,p,H,...,M)+(1-a)F(x,z',p',...,M').$ I don't understand this :(.

Comment: That's not very helpful, is it? What are $F,z,p,H,\ldots,M$? w.r.t. your problem?

Comment: I don't know. That was the definition given by the teacher, but then the equation isn't linear? If the equation isn't linear, then is semilinear always? :).

Comment: I think it's neither of the three, based on the definitions I could glean on the web. But there's nothing I can do to help you if you don't even know the proper definitions.